# Reduce array to set in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, set, reduce

I am trying to reduce an array of objects to a set in Swift and this is my code:

```
objects.reduce(Set<String>()) { $0.insert($1.URL) }
```

However, I get an error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

I do not understand what the problem is, since the type of URL is definitely String. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the signature for reduce is `func reduce<T>(_ initial: T, @noescape combine combine: (T, Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> T` which is not what you're passing.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You don't have to reduce an array to get it into a set; just create the set with an array: `let objectSet = Set(objects.map { $0.URL })`.

Comment: But I do not want the set of objects, but the set of different URLs that these objects have. I guess I could do a map and then Set(map), but I should be able to achieve this with reduce.

Comment: Ah. Then `let objectSet = Set(objects.map { $0.URL })`.

Comment: Ah, okay, great. Could you maybe edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It depends. If you map/flatmap its nice to chain calls.

Answer (score 39):

With Swift 5.1, you can use one of the three following examples in order to solve your problem.

---

## #1. Using `Array`'s [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) method and `Set`'s [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/3128843-init) initializer

In the simplest case, you can map you initial array to an array of `url`s (`String`) then create a set from that array. The Playground below code shows how to do it:

```
struct MyObject {
    let url: String
}

let objectArray = [
    MyObject(url: "mozilla.org"),
    MyObject(url: "gnu.org"),
    MyObject(url: "git-scm.com")
]

let urlArray = objectArray.map({ $0.url })
let urlSet = Set(urlArray)
dump(urlSet)
// ▿ 3 members
//   - "git-scm.com"
//   - "mozilla.org"
//   - "gnu.org"
```

---

## #2. Using `Array`'s [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce) method

```
struct MyObject {
    let url: String
}

let objectArray = [
    MyObject(url: "mozilla.org"),
    MyObject(url: "gnu.org"),
    MyObject(url: "git-scm.com")
]

let urlSet = objectArray.reduce(into: Set<String>(), { (urls, object) in
    urls.insert(object.url)
})
dump(urlSet)
// ▿ 3 members
//   - "git-scm.com"
//   - "mozilla.org"
//   - "gnu.org"
```

As an alternative, you can use `Array`'s [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) method:

```
struct MyObject {
    let url: String
}

let objectArray = [
    MyObject(url: "mozilla.org"),
    MyObject(url: "gnu.org"),
    MyObject(url: "git-scm.com")
]

let urlSet = objectArray.reduce(Set<String>(), { (partialSet, object) in
    var urls = partialSet
    urls.insert(object.url)
    return urls
})
dump(urlSet)
// ▿ 3 members
//   - "git-scm.com"
//   - "mozilla.org"
//   - "gnu.org"
```

---

## #3. Using an `Array` extension

If necessary, you can create a `mapToSet` method for `Array` that takes a `transform` closure parameter and returns a `Set`. The Playground below code shows how to use it:

```
extension Array {

    func mapToSet<T: Hashable>(_ transform: (Element) -> T) -> Set<T> {
        var result = Set<T>()
        for item in self {
            result.insert(transform(item))
        }
        return result
    }

}

struct MyObject {
    let url: String
}

let objectArray = [
    MyObject(url: "mozilla.org"),
    MyObject(url: "gnu.org"),
    MyObject(url: "git-scm.com")
]

let urlSet = objectArray.mapToSet({ $0.url })
dump(urlSet)
// ▿ 3 members
//   - "git-scm.com"
//   - "mozilla.org"
//   - "gnu.org"
```

Answer (score 5):

`reduce()` method expects a closure that *returns* a combined value, while `insert()` methods of `Set` value does not return anything but instead it inserts a new element into the existing set.

In order to make it work you would need to do something like:

```
objects.reduce(Set<String>()) {
    $0.union(CollectionOfOne($1.URL))
}
```

But the above is a bit of an unnecessary complication.  If you have a big array, that would mean quite a number of ever-growing sets to be created while Swift goes over all the elements from `objects`.  Better follow the advice from @NRitH and use `map()` as that would make a resulting set in one go.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it clarifies the problem for me.

Comment: @Banana, np.  See my edited answer.  It turns out to be not only over-complicating but also an inefficient thing to do.

Comment: This is a really bad solution. Each time you creates a new set instanse. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/3128858-union . Union Returns a new set.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 1.0-2.x ONLY:

If `URL` on your object is a strongly-typed `String`, you can create a new `Set<String>` object and use `unionInPlace` on the set with the mapped array:

```
var mySet = Set<String>()
mySet.unionInPlace(objects.map { $0.URL as String })
```

Comment: This should be `formUnion`. `unionInPlace` is not part of Swift

Comment: Hey @Drew, this answer was written in December 2015, when `unionInPlace` was part of Swift 2.