# Create Set of Array in Swift

Tags: swift

I was trying to create a **set** out of an **array** to make elements unique.
I thought it would be an elegant approach to use the Set initializer to do this job. So I created an **array** and tried to initialize my new **set** using that array.
But the compiler was complaining. I tried it using Integer values and it works like a charm. But with my own class it does not work. I also thought that the `Equatable Protocol` is the right way to go .. but as you see, it does not solve my Problem.

Consider the following Playground:

```
 import UIKit

internal struct Object: Equatable {
    var a: Int
}

internal func == (lhs:Object,rhs: Object) -> Bool {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a
}

let array = [Object(a:1),Object(a:1),Object(a:1),Object(a:1),Object(a:2)]

let set = Set(array) // ERROR
```

The Compiler is complaining with

> can not invoke initializer Set<_> with argument of type [Object]

Which Protocol do I need to implement to makes things work?

Comment: `Object` must conform to `Hashable`, not just `Equatable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce array to set in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161786/reduce-array-to-set-in-swift)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I am explicitly asking about the kind of protocol I need to implement. The referenced Thread says nothing about the Hashable Protocol and consists of constructs using reduce which could lead the developer to the wrong solution. This Post is more precise and should not be marked as a duplicate to help other stack overflow users finding a solution for their problem faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you 'command-click' on `Set` in Xcode, it takes you to the definition of the `Set` type. And there you go:

```
/// A collection of unique `Element` instances with no defined ordering.
public struct Set<Element : Hashable> : Hashable, CollectionType ...
```

As mentioned by Rob the elements need to confirm to `Hashable` (which in turn requires `Equatable`).

Adjusting your code:

```
import Foundation

internal struct Object: Hashable {
    var a: Int
    var hashValue: Int { return a.hash }
}

internal func == (lhs:Object,rhs: Object) -> Bool {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a
}

let array = [Object(a:1),Object(a:1),Object(a:1),Object(a:1),Object(a:2)]

let set = Set(array) // SUCCESS
```